# jqBootstrapValidation on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using jqBootstrapValidation on a form inside a boostrap dialog, and I use the dialog's submit button for ajax form submitting.

If there is no focus (no click inside any fields), i can submit it and no verification are done. Ho prevent submit if content is empty using dialog form ?

Or there is a true/false/1/0 value I can check before allow submitting ?

Thnks for your help,
mike

Comment: My jquery call :

$('#editLink').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#modal-change-type-form').submit();

});

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but it may help someone else:

```
$("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
});
```

Comment: It's never too late, thanks, but it not work in my case. I add detail in my question